# how to change equation label positions in excel chart via c#?

Tags: c#, excel, charts, equation, trendline

I would like advice on how to change the position of the label in which the regression equation and R2 are in the graph in Excel. The chart was created via C#. The attached pictures show how it is and how it should be.

| Wrong | Correct |
| --- | --- |
| [image: wrong] | [image: correct] |

Thanks

```cs
Excel.Range chart_range;

chart_range = xlsheet.get_Range("B:B", "C:C");
Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlsheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 600, 400);
Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlLine;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
chartPage.SetSourceData(chart_range, misValue);

Excel.Axis axis = (Excel.Axis)chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory,Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
axis.CategoryType = Excel.XlCategoryType.xlCategoryScale;

// regression equation + trendline
Excel.Series series = chartPage.SeriesCollection(1);
Excel.Trendlines trendlines = series.Trendlines();
trendlines.Add(Excel.XlTrendlineType.xlLinear,DisplayEquation:true, DisplayRSquared:true);
```

I need advice on how to move a label in a graph using C#.

Comment: Why not use a template, then you can pre-position the legend?

Answer (score 0):

```
trendlines.DataLabel.Left = 0;
trendlines.DataLabel.Top = 0;
```

Please experiment with the values accordingly.